# How to sample 90/10 split% rows out of 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(10L,14L,9L,42L,67L,3L,54L,93L,34L,22L), Col2 = c(20L,34L,29L,7L,11L,67L,84L,73L,35L,58L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

which looks like:

```
Col1 Col2
10   20
14   34
9    29
42   7
67   11
3    67
54   84
93   73
34   35
22   58
```

I want to append a new column `Col3` that samples 10% of row elements of `Col1` and 90% of row elements of `Col2`. So an acceptable output would look like the below:

```
df_new <- structure(list(Col1 = c(10L,14L,9L,42L,67L,3L,54L,93L,34L,22L), 
                     Col2 = c(20L,34L,29L,7L,11L,67L,84L,73L,35L,58L),
                     Col3 = c(10L,14L,9L,7L,11L,67L,84L,73L,35L,58L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Do you want exactly 10% of row elements (i.e. here 1 element) drawn from Col1, or the elements drawn from Col1 with a probability of 10%?

Comment: Always 10% from Co1. So for example, if we have 250 rows in the data frame, then Col3 shall take 25 rows from Col1 and 225 rows from Col2. Raw selection shall be random,not top 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two `dplyr` solutions.

Sampling Col1 with a probability of 10%:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Col3 = if_else(runif(nrow(.)) <= 0.1, Col1, Col2))
```

Sampling exactly 1/10 of values from Col1:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Col3 = if_else(sample(if_else(seq(nrow(.)) <= 0.1*nrow(.), T, F)), Col1, Col2))
```

Comment: Hi @Aron if I have few rows (20) this is not always sampling 2 rows which is 10%. Sometimes it samples 1 row while others 3 or 4 for example. Can I tackle this probabilistic issue?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use `sample`:

```
set.seed(1)
idx <- seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% sample(1:nrow(df), 0.9*nrow(df))

df$col3 <- ifelse(idx, df$Col1, df$Col2)


   Col1 Col2 col3
1    10   20   10
2    14   34   14
3     9   29    9
4    42    7   42
5    67   11   67
6     3   67    3
7    54   84   54
8    93   73   73
9    34   35   34
10   22   58   22
```

Comment: answer worked but could you adapt the following to be
`df$col3 <- ifelse(idx, df$Col2, df$Col1)`
to reflect the desired 10% of Col1 and 90% of Col2 as described in the question.

Comment: yeah sure just put `Col2` first and `Col1` second in the definition of `Col3`. 
Note that the 90% mixture is already inside the defintion of `sample` where I use `0.9 * nrow(df)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do,

```
c(sample(dd$Col1, 0.1 * nrow(dd)), sample(dd$Col2, 0.9 * nrow(dd)))
#[1]  9 20 58  7 29 35 73 11 34 84
```

Comment: this was my first approach as well. This solves the problem as stated by the OP but I think they wanted a little bit more. Namely, the first entry of the new column should be either the first row of `Col1` or `Col2` and not an arbitrary element of `Col1` and `Col2`.

Comment: @Cettt I don't see that in the question....but even If this is the case then they can easily change the order in `c()` and sample the 2nd col first...

Answer (score 0):

similar to the approach by [@Aron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59880458/12158757) but with base R, using `ifelse()`

```
df <- within(df,Col3 <- ifelse(runif(nrow(df))<0.1,Col1,Col2))
```